Auto updating values with api
I'm not sure if I said it correctly, I'm new to Javascript and coding in general. Here is what I actually want:
I want to create discord bot that will send reports from PUBG matches, I got the api key from PUBG and I can access data, now I am wondering how can I make it update every time new match is played by specific player.
Thank you for your help
edit: to be more precise, there is array of objects, how to detect change on array[0]
